# How do I get all available variables for a Mustache Template?

Tags: javascript, html, mustache

I have a complex system that has a template. Unfortunately, I can't find where the template is being called. I would like to know all of the variables passed to the template when it was rendered. Is there a special command I can use inside the double brackets? {{[something cool here]}}

Thanks.

Comment: Depending upon what exactly your data is like, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058774/handlebars-mustache-is-there-a-built-in-way-to-loop-through-the-properties-of) may be the answer you need and another relevant answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19800602/how-to-see-all-available-variables-in-handlebars-template).  You could also send `this` to a customer helper and do `console.log(JSON.stringify(arg)))` to see what the data is.

Answer (score 2):

`{{this}}` would do the trick. Maybe not very readable, but quick and easy