# Is there a way to console.log date(timestamp) with handlebars

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, hapi.js

Is there a way to console.log the value in input type date?

```
<input type="date" value="{{moment date=d format='YYYY-MM-DD' subtract='days' amount='2'}}" style="position: relative; float: left; top: 130px;" />
```

I'm using handlebars in combination with hapi and i'm trying to get a user to select "from" and "to" date with  and use that selection to specify what information to retrieve based on date (timestamp).

Comment: you can done like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499742/how-do-i-add-console-log-javascript-logic-inside-of-a-handlebars-template

Answer (score 4):

You can use [ember log helper](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_log).