# Check status in handlebars

Tags: javascript, sails.js, handlebars.js

Hi I want to check the string response in HB. I've tried this:

```
{{#if status=='false'}}
    {{console.log("hi");}}
{{else}}
   {{console.log("no");}}
{{#endif}}
```

How can I check the response simple? I want to show a message if it's true and another message if it's false.

Comment: Possibly answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499742/how-do-i-add-console-log-javascript-logic-inside-of-a-handlebars-template Please check.

Answer (score 0):

Handlebars is designed to be very simple and doesn't have this functionality out of the box. You should pass the status as a boolean rather than a string, then just use an if statement:

```
{{#if status}}
    {{console.log("hi");}}
{{else}}
   {{console.log("no");}}
{{#endif}}
```

You could also write a helper function:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('ifEq', function(a, b, options) {
  if (a == b) return options.fn(this)
  else return options.inverse(this)
});
```

Then your handlebars becomes:

```
{{#ifEq status 'true'}}
  Hello
{{else}}
  No
{{/ifEq}}
```

Comment: I've got this error: message": "Missing helper: \"ifEq\"",
  "name": "Error",
  "stack": "Error: Missing helper:

Comment: You need to register the helper function as above with `Handlebars.registerHelper`

Comment: @Hateres1990 please look up handlebars helpers and how to register them.